# making JSON from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a job to refractor strings to start using json so they can just pass json objects. So I have made array of names and then I'm trying to go through and make key and values but I'm getting an error in the console that it cant find x of no value. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
 var newName = ['ManagingOrg', 'ActiveOrg', 'Severity', 'SeverityClassification', 'WorkQueue', 'TicketState',................ to long to post];


            $().each(newName, function (key, value) {
                key = newName[this];
                value = newValues[this] = $('#' + key).val();
                newArray = [key][value];
                newArray = JSON.stringify(newArray);
                alert(newArray);
                $('.results').html(origArray[TicketNumber]);

            });
```

Comment: Is there an extra comma at the end of the newName array?

Comment: nope! I know perl needs the stuff but I tried to dumb it down because the actual code would need to look like this in the end. value = newValues[this] = $('#' + key).val(); I could just make json but its like 100 plus fields and there needs to be 4 so I thought this would be easy and dynamic for future edits.

Comment: What exactly states the error in your console? And at which line?

Comment: Unable to get property 'ManagingOrg' of undefined or null reference

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1E0E5FD2F1368474!30255&authkey=!AGG3_Bd9UeRQLds&ithint=folder%2cPNG

Comment: When in doubt try reading the docs and look at examples [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have "newValues" and "origArray" defined elsewhere?

In any case you'll need to at least adjust the following:

- "$().each" should be `$.each`
- "newArray" should be defined outside and you should use `newArray[key] = value`
- you don't have a variable "TicketNumber" defined and so you should wrap "TicketNumber" in quotes
- **this** is a reserved word so you shouldn't use it in "newName[this]" or "newValues[this]"

I suggest using a `for` loop instead of `$.each()` based on what you're trying to do inside.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx

Comment: I do like your suggestions I do have one question. If I initialize newArray[key] = value that means I would need to create the key and value and would that not create the json or just an array?

Comment: Actually, defining "newArray" as an object, `var newArray = {}`, prior to the loop will give you an object that you can stringify after your loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
var origArray = [];

    var newName = ['ManagingOrg', 'ActiveOrg', 'Severity', 'SeverityClassification'
    ];


    for (var i = 0; i < newName.length - 1; i++) {
        var object = {};
        object[newName[i]] = newName[i];
        object = JSON.stringify(object);
        origArray.push(object);

    }
```